# Powershell Script to Return Directories Without a Zip File Created/Modified Within the Last 7 Days

Tags: script, powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a series of folders on a server that needs to be regularly checked that they are being backed up correctly. We like to have at least 1 backup in that folder that is no less than 7 days old. The backups are in .zip format.

I want to be able to see the directories that **do not** contain any zip files that have been modified or created in the last 7 days.

Here is an example of what the file structure looks like:

```
\\server01\backups\PLANT1\A
\\server01\backups\PLANT1\B
\\server01\backups\PLANT2\A
\\server01\backups\PLANT2\B
...etc
```

I managed to put together a powershell script that returns the entire directory of zip files and another that lists the ones that have been modified in the last 7 days, but not one that returns only the directories of those that do not have the files we need.

Here is that script I just mentioned:

```
$DateToCompare = (Get-date).AddDays(-7)
Get-ChildItem \\server01\backups -recurse -include *.zip | Where {(!$_.PsIsContainer) -and ($_.lastwritetime -gt $DateToCompare)} | select DirectoryName,Name,LastWriteTime | sort DirectoryName
```

Your guidance is much appreciated.

Edit:

Here is the code in its final form. I was really close.

```
$DateToCompare = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)
Get-ChildItem \\server01\backups -recurse -include *.zip | Where {(!$_.PsIsContainer) -Notcontains ($_.creationtime -gt $DateToCompare)} | select DirectoryName,Name,CreationTime | sort DirectoryName
```

Comment: You're right at the finish line. I believe the last step you're looking for is to use the "-notcontains" flag in your where clause. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74957/is-there-a-powershell-string-does-not-contain-cmdlet-or-syntax

Comment: Yes! That is it! If you would like to give an actual answer I'd love to give you credit.

Comment: Glad this helped! You should post your edited code for us to see for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only piece of the puzzle you're missing here is the "-notcontains" flag, to be asserted in your "Where" clause. You know exactly what you want to get *rid* of, but the code you've posted *shows* exactly what you don't want. Choose to "exclude" rather than "select only" your specified items with -notcontains.

Source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692798.aspx

Comment: Thanks again for the help. Any idea how I could simply modify the above script to only return directories that do not contain zip files older than 7 days and did not have zip files that were within the 7 days?

Comment: (I'm hoping that I understand your question correctly). To return only the directories of this query you could simply remove Name and CreationTime from your Select.

This will still return the ever-ugly "DirectoryName -------------" header at the top, but you can easily trim that off so the output is plainly the directories with `ft -HideTableHeaders`. So for the final you can use:

`Get-ChildItem \\server01\backups -recurse -include *.zip | Where {(!$_.PsIsContainer) -Notcontains ($_.creationtime -gt $DateToCompare)} | select DirectoryName | sort DirectoryName | ft -HideTableHeaders`